# Unable to upload image files to S3 bucket from Heroku hosted Django project with boto3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a Django project where entertainers register and part of the process is to upload a profile image as well as up to 5 gallery images. 
My project is hosted on Heroku and static and media files are stored in an S3 bucket. This is my first time using s3 buckets so I have granted as much access as possible to try to get it to work
I am trying to dynamically generate the location of the images based on the title of the entertainer so my entertainer/models.py is set up as follows:

```
def profile_image_path(instance,filename):
    upload_dir = os.path.join('profile/', instance.title)
    if not os.path.exists(upload_dir):
        os.makedirs(upload_dir)
    return os.path.join(upload_dir, filename)


def img1_image_path(instance,filename):
    upload_dir = os.path.join('img1/', instance.title)
    if not os.path.exists(upload_dir):
        os.makedirs(upload_dir)
    return os.path.join(upload_dir, filename)

title = models.CharField(
    max_length = 15
)

profile_image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to = profile_image_path,
    default = 'no_image.png'
)

image1 = models.ImageField(
    upload_to = img1_image_path,
    default = 'no_image.png'
)
```

etc

The idea is that images will get stored in the S3 bucket as follows:

- media/profile//profile.jpg
- media/img1//img1.jpg
- media/img2//img2.jpg
  etc

However when I register an entertainer I can see on the heroku database as well as the interface of my app that the default image is being used instead of what I upload. The default image (no_image.png) was previously manually uploaded to the bucket and my app is able to see it. Also if I manually upload the images and update the profile image location in the heroku database, my app can also see it.
Basically it looks like I have read access to the bucket and am unable to write to it from my app.

My S3 Bucket Policy is as follows

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bookanentertainer"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bookanentertainer/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My CORS Configuration is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
       <CORSRule>
            <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
            <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
            <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
            <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
            <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
            <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
       </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
```

My bucket is set to "Public Access"
Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you have your config-file: Keys to your bucket and how are they called? With [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for example, you need `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` to be able to save an image to your bucket.

Comment: Both are in my settings/base.py file. I think though the issue is with permissions?